# I am getting error of config file not found while set up of ory hydra

Tags: oauth-2.0, hydra

```
docker run --network hydraguide --name ory-hydra-example--postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=hydra -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -e POSTGRES_DB=hydra -d postgres:9.6
```

When i run the above command as mentioned in hydra docs i get the error as below

```
Config file not found because "Config File ".hydra" Not Found in "[/]""
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that error does not appear anymore in newer versions of [ORY Hydra](https://github.com/ory/hydra).
Are you using the latest version?